# .htaccess file and clean Urls problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I've been using the same .htaccess file to remove the .php extension in my sites. I can't seem to figure out what doesn't work this time. Its a new hosting provider I registered with.I tried making a simple redirect to SO to see if the file was getting parsed,It does. I read the whole Apache Mod_rewrite book and understand what the file does but there's something I'm missing.Thanks in advance for the help.here's the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php [L]
```

Btw It's in the public_html folder which shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Just found the solution to my problem.I m using this now:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page-name\.html$ page-name.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```